# use of a JToolTip

Tags: java, swing

I want to use that class and not call on a JComponent setToolTipText method but the code
below not show the tooltip:

```
JButton btn = new JButtn("SAVE");
JToolTip tip_for_button = new JToolTip();
tip_for_button.setTipText("blah blah");
tip_for_button.setComponent(btn);
```

why?

Comment: You need to add more code, ideally a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). As such, it's hard to answer you, since we miss all the context. What you provided is not enough to describe the problem.

Comment: The above components are simply inserted into a JFrame's windows with a BorderLayout container... and I don't think it's necessary to show that for problem resolution.
Thanks, however.

Answer (score 3):

Well, because all the code that actually catches the mouse event and shows the tooltip is  in `ToolTipManager` (the instance of this class is singleton, unique in the application), and `ToolTipManager` always calls `JComponent.createToolTip()` method on component when determining what tooltip to show. So if you want to use your own tooltip you have to override this method and write something like this:

```
JButton btn = new JButton("SAVE"){

        public JToolTip createToolTip() {
           JToolTip tip_for_button = new JToolTip(){
               public String getTipText() {
                   return "blah blah";
               }
           };
           tip_for_button.setComponent(this);
           return tip_for_button;
       }
       };
       btn.setToolTipText("notnull");
```

`setToolTipText` is mandatory, or the tooltip will not show, and the text passed to it is always set to the tooltip created by Component, so if you want the immutable text, you override `JToolTip.getTipText()`.

Comment: Hum, I tried this, but it does not work... are you sure it works for you ?

Comment: Thx, by reading the API and making tries, my conclusion was also that without calling setToolTipText(), no tooltip is displayed. I don't know if we're right, but for the moment, only this solution seems to work...

Comment: @Sylvain M Yes, we are right. In the source code of ToolTipManager in the class that manages the showing of the tooltip when mouse enters the component ($insideTimerAction) there is this code (I cut out the irrelevant lines): toolTipText = insideComponent.getToolTipText(mouseEvent);              
                if(toolTipText != null) {
                    showImmediately = true;
                    showTipWindow();
                }
else{
hideTipWindow();
}

Comment: However if we remove btn.setToolTipText("notnull") and put       
ToolTipManager toolTipManager = ToolTipManager.sharedInstance();
toolTipManager.registerComponent(btn);
the tooltip show only with CTRL+F1 but not with mouse over the component!!!! Strange Strange

Comment: @xdevel2000  as I've said, in the code ToolTipManager$insideTimerAction the getToolTipText is checked to be not null, and this class manages the tooltips for mouse over event. I really don't understand why JToolTip.getText isn't checked instead, or why getToolTipText isn't checked in other methods, but well.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to call setToolTipText(). See http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html for details.

Comment: Though he states he doesn't want to use "setToolTipText()".

Answer (score 0):

What is `tip_for_button`? For it to work I am pretty sure that `tip_for_button` needs to be `tip`